# undefined helper function in laravel phpunit testcase

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I've a helper file `helper.php` where I keep some helper functions.

```
//helper.php
function isAuthLiked($authLikedPosts, $post)
{
    return !! Auth::check() && $authLikedPosts->contains('id', $post->id);
}
```

Now in my test case, I wrote:

```
    $this->assertTrue(isAuthLiked($authrenominations, $post[0]));
```

When I ran the test case, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function isAuthLiked() in
>   C:\wamp\www\Nom7\tests\integration\UserTest.php on line 304

I've added the helper file in the compose.json auto-load. But the problem persists.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Http/Controllers",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "files":[
        "app/helper.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Acme\\": "app/Acme/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "files":[
        "app/helper.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Could you post your composer.json?

Comment: @Schellingerht: Added.

Comment: Can use use this function outside your tests?

Comment: Yes I can use the helper functions outside the testcases and it's working fine.

Comment: Does it work it you reference the class in your test case like this: `$this->assertTrue(Helper::isAuthLiked($authrenominations, $post[0]));`
given that you have a alias for your "helper.php"-class with the name "Helper". Or if you give a reference to the class like this:
`$this->assertTrue(\Path\To\File\helper::isAuthLiked($authrenominations, $post[0]));`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your path. You are using *relative paths* in your files array. You are running your tests from your tests directory, so cannot find app/helper.php

Comment: I changed the namespace to App and then i tried, still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Namespace? The files array must contain files without namespace.

Comment: I mean in the TestCase.php class. Not in the compose.json